# Unresolved Dependency in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I am trying to use play-authenticate and deadbolt plugin in a sample Play Framework application

My build.sbt looks like this

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.0-RC1",
  "com.feth"      %%  "play-authenticate" % "0.6.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

)

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository (release)", url("http://schaloner.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository (snapshot)", url("http://schaloner.github.com/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
Resolver.url("play-easymail (release)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
Resolver.url("play-easymail (snapshot)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
Resolver.url("play-authenticate (release)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/repo/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
Resolver.url("play-authenticate (snapshot)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-authenticate/repo/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

)

But i am getting the following error
**sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.feth#play-authenticate_2.11;0.6.1-SNAPSHOT: not found**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this sample project](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/build.sbt#L21), update your `resolvers` to the following:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository (release)", url("http://schaloner.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository (snapshot)", url("http://schaloner.github.com/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  "play-easymail (release)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-easymail/repo/releases/",
  "play-easymail (snapshot)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-easymail/repo/snapshots/",
  "play-authenticate (release)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/repo/releases/",
  "play-authenticate (snapshot)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/repo/snapshots/"
)
```